# Pros/Cons of Foreign Ordinary Shares vs International Markets

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, investing, international

As a US investor I have several options to invest in foreign equities:

- Direct investing in a foreign market (ASX, TSX, TSXV, etc.)
- ADRs (Y-class shares on OTC, not always a 1:1 ratio)
- Foreign Ordinary Shares (F-class shares on OTC)

Currently I invest in foreign stocks via the latter method, as its available in USD and I trade through stocks that are not considered penny-stocks and are all on the OTCQB/QX (never Pink). The downside to this tends to be a lower liquidity which gives a wider spread. One of the reasons I might want to trade on on a foreign market is exactly that, higher liquidity, but with that comes currency conversions and foreign tax implications. From what I understand, Foreign Ordinaries are not dividend eligible like ADRs and foreign market holdings are; thus they don't need to worry about those foreign tax implications either (such as a withholding fee/tax).

Thus I have several questions:

1. Is it true that Foreign Ordinaries are not dividend eligible?
2. Since Foreign Ordinaries trade in the US, they are not subject to foreign market taxes, correct?
3. What are the pros/cons for investing in Foreign Ordinaries vs International Markets (or vice versa)?

Comment: Where did you hear that F-class OTC are not eligible for dividends?